# VBA Copy Whole Column From SQL Recordset

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a fixed data set of 6 rows being queried in SQL. I want to transfer the data in this query into Excel. My question is in two parts:

1 - Can I pull back multiple columns in one go or do I have to do it column by column? I have 17 columns and 6 rows. As this is transferred into my Excel template I'm looking to break this up into thirds so columns 1 to 7 go in one space 8 to 11 in another section and 12 to 17 in another section in Excel.

2 - When using my current code of:

```
Range("F2").Value = rst.Fields("ACCOUNT")
```

I only pull back a single row, is it possible to get the whole column (all 6 rows) or do I have to loop all 6 rows to get the full column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.GetRows()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado), it allows to set a number of records to retrieve, first record to begin, and single field name or ordinal position, or an array of field names or ordinal position numbers.

The below example shows how to get data from external Excel workbook into recordset, retrieve specified fields into array, and paste result array to the worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sConnection As String
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim oConnection As Object
    Dim oRecordset As Object
    Dim aData()

    sConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"

    sQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src1.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "WHERE Country='UK';"

    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConnection.Open sConnection
    Set oRecordset = oConnection.Execute(sQuery)
    oRecordset.MoveFirst
    aData = oRecordset.GetRows(, , Array("CustomerID", "ContactName"))
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        Output2DArray .Cells(1, 1), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aData)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    oConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Also there is `Src1.xlsx` workbook containing [Customers](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) as data source in the same folder as this workbook:

[image: src1]

The resulting worksheet is as follows, you can see there are `CustomerID` and `ContactName` fields only:

[image: result]