# CopyFromRecordset only specific column into Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to get a particular column only in a specified range. The Recordset contains multiple columns. 
For testing, I would need column 1 into Range A, Column 2 in Range E

```
Set rstData = New ADODB.Recordset     
strSQLData = " SELECT  [Name] ,[Surname] FROM mytable "   
rstData.Open strSQLData, Cnxn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'This line copies all data in Range 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(-23, 5).CopyFromRecordset rstData

'This command copies first column of recordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(-23, 5).CopyFromRecordset rstData, , 1
```

I would need something like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(-23, 5).CopyFromRecordset rstData('Name').Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(-23, 10).CopyFromRecordset rstData("Surname").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.GetRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao) method to achieve this.

So you can set **(Code Untested)**

```
Dim data()
data = rstData.GetRows("CustomerID")
```

to get the column names "CustomerID" from the Recordset

**Note:** It returns a 2-D array, and read about it from the link to know many more options available and how to use.

[Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036666/vba-copy-whole-column-from-sql-recordset)

Answer (score 0):

The following example will insert Field1 and Field3 from the recordset into Excel columns A and B. Then it will insert Field4 from the recordset into Excel column C.

For more on GetRows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16

```
Dim a, b As Variant

'GetRows(Rows, Start, Fields )  
a = rstdata.getrows(, 1, Array("Field1", "Field3"))
b = rstdata.getrows(, 1, "Field4")
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(a, 2) + 1, UBound(a, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Resize(UBound(b, 2) + 1, UBound(b, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(b)
```